# difference between two dates in days in php using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a customer form in two date fields. Actually i find the days between in customer_birthday date and customer_marriage date. i'll try this code to fulfill my problem but its doesn't work.
where i am wrong.

**My controller code**

```
$date1=$_POST['customer_birth'];
$date2=$_POST['customer_marriage'];
$datediff = $date1 - $date2;
echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24)); exit ;
```

its gives me output is 0

thanks for help

Comment: What's value of `$date1` and `$date2`?

Comment: FYI not all days are 24 hours long and not all minutes are 60 seconds long

Comment: the $date1 holds the mm/dd/yyyy format 06/22/2017 and $date2 holds 06/24/2017

Comment: @DevendraSingh check my answer given below

Answer (score 4):

use `date_diff()` function of php to calculate the diffrence between two dates

```
<?php
    $date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
    $date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);//OP: +272 days 
?>
```

You can check the mannual here [PHP date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 2):

Best way you can follow below solution.

```
$date1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['customer_birth']));
$date2 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['customer_marriage']));

$diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));

$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: @DevendraSingh: Glad to help you out from this hurdle.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is....

```
$date1      = date_create('2015-07-31');
$date2      = date_create('2016-07-31');
$diff       = date_diff($date1,$date2);
$days       = $diff->format("%a")+1;
```

Comment: `%a` is the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this code

```
$datetime1 = date_create($user['datee']);

$datetime2 = date_create($user['date1']);

$interval  = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);

$x = @($interval->format('%R%a days')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with compare timestamp of times:

```
$date1 = '06/22/2017';
$date2 = '06/24/2017';

$datediff = (strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
echo floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should helps you:

```
$date1 = strtotime($date1);
$date2 = strtotime($date2);
$datediff = $date1 - $date2;

$no_of_days =  floor($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

var_dump($no_of_days );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$from_data = date('m',strtotime('11-10-2022 12:12:00'));
$to_date = date('m',strtotime('13-10-2022 10:12:0'));

$month_difference = $to_date - $from_date;
```